# Origin of the verb "doppiare" in the nautical slang

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, etymology

I noticed an inconsistency between the English word **round** and the Italian translation **doppiare**;
in the nautical slang we use *round* with the meaning of move/go/pass through a cape;
*i.e. round the Cape of Good Hope*

Translating it in Italian I noticed a peculiarity since *doppiare* comes from *doppio*, that is *twice*, and it is **not logical**, since when we overcome an obstacle we pass it, we do not pass it twice...

What is the origin of the Italian word?

Comment: It's not a complete answer, but according to the [Vocabulary Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/doppiare1/) in this meaning it comes from the Spanish *doblar*. Maybe someone else can shed light on how this meaning arose in Spanish

Comment: @DenisNardin doblar comes from latin word *duplāre*... this is not the right way...

Comment: It is clear that the link is with *double*, in Spanish, in Italian and in Latin. The problem, as I see in the question,  is which is the connection between *double* and *passing through a cape*, which seems not so obvious.

Comment: “it is not logical”: since when are natural languages logical?  :)

Comment: "Double a cape" is a thing in English as well.

Comment: I just asked it on Spanish.SE: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42566/how-did-doblar-come-to-mean-turn

Comment: The double meaning *raddoppiare* and *curvare* is also in the Latin verb *duplico* https://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-italiano.php?lemma=DUPLICO100 . I wonder if the verb *duplo* is a contraction of *duplico*.  So, it seems to me that the connection between *doppiare* and *curvare* is not suprising, *curvare* is *making double*.

Comment: @BakerStreet: [Lewis & Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DD%3Aentry+group%3D55%3Aentry%3Dduplo1): _dū^plo, āre, v. a. id._, to double (only in jurid. Lat., for the class. _duplico_)

Comment: I didn't understand. Are *duplo* and *duplico* the same verb or not? They have different origins, even if the meaning is the same?  And Lewis & Short says that *duplo* is a juridical term? Or *duplico* is a juridical term? I don't believe it, it is strange.

Comment: Evidentemente vengono entrambi da *piega*, *-plek*   indoeuropeo* o  *plica* in latino, ma non so se sono verbi che hanno avuto origini e destini diversi, o si possono considerare la stessa parola.

Comment: Per Levis et Brevis, sono i sinonimi, _duplo_ essendo usata solo nei contesti legali. I sinonimi possono totalmente originare dalle radice diverse. Tutte le fonti che sono riuscito a trovare dicono che _duplo_ e' originata da _duplus_, ma forse si tratta di una analisi superficiale ("surface analysis", non so se si dica giusto cosi' in italiano). Ma se e' vero che _duplo_ e' originata da _duplus_, mi rusulta che non abbia niente a che fare con _-plek_, bensi' con _-pleh1_  (> "piu'", "pieno")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148936/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-bakerstreet).

Answer (score 5):

I'm  certainly not an expert in boating, but I can give a possible answer about the meaning and the origin of the term *doppiare* in nautical language.

And about its connection with the term *doppio*.

Nautical terminology is very complicated and there are dictionaries on this subject.

The following is a *Dizionario del mare* (Dictionary of the Sea), of 1932, and  the entry *doppiare*  can shed light on our problem:

http://asa.archiviostudiadriatici.it/islandora/object/libria:97896/datastream/PDF/content/libria_97896.pdf

I put the image of the entry *doppiare* below:

[image: Definition of "doppiare" (part 1)]
[image: Definition of "doppiare" (part 2)]

Transcription:

> **Doppiare** termine proprio della marina.  Significa passare a breve distanza, descrivendo un breve giro, dall’una all’altra parte di un capo, di una punta, di un'isola. Quando si passa in linea retta si dice: *montare*.

The dictionary describes **two ways of passing through a cape, *doppiare* and *montare*.**

*Doppiare un capo* means passing a short distance from a cape (or an island), describing a turn. Instead, when the cape is passed along a straight line the term is *montare*.

Therefore, but this is my conjecture, when a boat *doppia* a cape, it goes, in a sense, twice along the cape: it goes along the first side, then it passes the point of the cape and then goes again along the other side of the cape.

This seems to me not very different from the English term 'round', which also suggests a curved movement, not a straight line.

And **the origin from the Spanish term *doblar***,  mentioned by Denis Nardin in the comments, seems to confirm this connection between *curvare, girare* and *raddoppiare*,  both present in the Spanish term *doblar*.

Comment: I like your explanation; let's see if someone else can prove it

Comment: cf English "double back", to turn around and go back on the same path. Not the same, but also not entirely dissimilar.

Comment: I see, interesting, thank you.

Comment: I think one possible connection to "doppio" is about ropes. Doing a "double-rope" (corda doppia in Italian) using a single rope makes it draw a tight round turn on one end.

Comment: I don't understand why you rejected my edit.

Comment: I thank you for improving my English, but the insertion of the link to the dictionary in the body of the text and the photo was a choice. This dictionary, in my opinion, is interesting and beautiful and I want to put it in evidence.  I prefer the entry of the dictionary, also, to be visible as a document, so I inserted the photo. Simply, I don’t like the link in the footnote and the text of the entry copied from the original:  I like this dictionary I found, and I want to highlight it and share the document. The link and the photo are integral parts of the text of the answer.

Comment: I like the dictionary too.  I wasn't suggesting to remove the link to it, I just wanted to incorporate the hyperlink into the text of the answer (rather than leaving it as a bare URL).  Having images of text is an accessibility issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, Element in Space, It's the same, i don't like the hyperlink in this case, I have my preferences and my rules about this matter of using hyperlinks, not everything can or must be a hyperlink. And images on Stack Exchange are everywhere, when needed and useful, some sites are unconceivable without images. This is my answer, these are my preferences and my style. I think  the answer this way is clearer, more informative, and  more beautiful (also aesthetic reasons, yes). It is a subjective matter, but I can't accept an edit to an answer of mine that I think  is not an improvement.

Comment: I don't have a problem with images in general.  
However, images of text is accessibility issue, as are images with alt-text reading "enter image description here".  
I've proposed another edit, thank you for considering it.

Comment: If you keep the photo of the original entry, ok, I can accept it, even if I'm not convinced of the utility, I find the transcrption reduntant and  a little visually confusing the text. (I find it ugly, to be sincere :-), I would avoid it).  But if you think that it is  somehow useful, ok.

Answer (score 1):

"To double" and its friends meaning "to round a cape" is a thing in many languages, including English, Italian, Spanish and French (and probably others).

I don't have anything to back it up with, but my hunch is that in this sense it's been conflated with or at least influenced by Latin *duplex* or one of its descendants (rather than its direct ancestor *duplus*), and it has more to do with the *-plex* part (whence *piegare* "to flex, bend") than with the *du-* part.

It probably happened in one Romance language and then got calqued by the other ones (and later borrowed by English).

If it were true, this word would have semantic parallels in many more languages, including Russian *обогнуть*, Homeric Greek *περιγνάμπτω*, English "to lap", all meaning "to go around an obstacle" and descending from a root meaning "to fold, bend".

Comment: La tua idea è interessante (+1), perché chiama in causa il suffisso moltiplicativo *-plex*, l’equivalente dell’italiano *-plice* e dell’inglese *-fold*. Che a sua volta viene dalla radice indoeuropea *-plek* (parte, piega, intreccio). Esprime  la complessità di un oggetto (in base al numero di piegamenti), duplice, semplice, molteplice etc. vedi ad esempio https://dico.unime.it/2016/02/17/la-complessita-del-semplice/ (è un servizio della Università di Messina).

Comment: Però, non mi è chiaro perché *doppiare* (dal *doblar* spagnolo,  a sua volta dal *duplare* latino) debba venire proprio da *duplex* e non da *simplex* o *triplex* o *complex* etc., visto che quello che importa è il suffisso *-plex.* Non lo so, possono avvenire pure cose strane nella storia della lingua, ma che possa esserci un  nesso tra *raddoppiare* e *piegare* mi sembra abbastanza intuitivo (‘due pieghe’), anche nel caso delle navi che girano intorno a un ostacolo.

Comment: In spagnolo questo doppio significato, *raddoppiare* e *piegare* di *doblar* è esplicito, e forse si potrebbe capire in spagnolo da dove viene questo duplice significato, ma non conosco lo spagnolo. Si potrebbe vedere anche il latino *duplare*, ma purtroppo ora non ho a disposizione il dizionario grande cartaceo, e quelli online sono inguardabili, per quel poco che ho visto.

Comment: Thanks @BakerStreet I did not know about DICO; I wrote them, too